# Backbone.Model validation and isValid

Tags: validation, backbone.js, coffeescript

I have set up my model validation like below

- Full CoffeeScript Code: http://pastebin.com/3isZZke8
- Demo on JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/XKTnb/

**Model's Validation**

```
class Todo extends Backbone.Model 
    validate: (attrs) -> 
        errs = {}
        hasErrors = false

        if (attrs.title is "")
            hasErrors = true
            errs.title = "Please specify a todo"

        if hasErrors
            return errs
```

**Error related code in View**

```
class TodoView extends Backbone.View

    events:
        "keypress .editing input[name=todo]": "saveTodo"
        "keyup .editing input[name=todo]": "closeEdit" 
        "blur input[name=todo]": "clearErrors"

    initialize: -> 
        ...
        @model.bind("change", @render)
        @model.bind("error", @handleError)

    saveTodo: (e) ->
        if e.type is "keypress" and e.charCode isnt 13
            return
        @model.set("title": @$("input[name=todo]").val())
        console.log @$("input[name=todo]").val() + "...", @model.isValid(), @model.get("title")
        if @model.isValid()
            @closeEdit()

    closeEdit: (e) ->
        if (e)
            if e.type is "keyup" and e.keyCode isnt 27 then return
        @$el.removeClass("editing") 

    handleError: (model, errs) ->
        @clearErrors()
        @$("input[name=todo]").after($("<span />", {
            class: "error",
            html: errs.title
        }));
        console.log "error handled"

    clearErrors: ->
        @$el.remove(".error")
```

In `TodoView.saveTodo`, I check if the model is valid, if so, I expect `save` to be successful and want to get out of edit edit mode. However, it appears `isValid` is always `true`, maybe because validation occurs and thus model is not saved thus in a valid state?

**UPDATE**

Added link to JS Fiddle above. Try adding a todo, then try to make the todo blank. Notice it closes the edit mode although in code I had:

```
saveTodo: (e) ->
    if e.type is "keypress" and e.charCode isnt 13
        return
    @model.set("title", @$("input[name=todo]").val())
    if @model.isValid() # model appears to be valid here!
        @model.save()
        @closeEdit()
```

Now double click to go into edit mode, notice the error is there meaning the validation was done correctly

Comment: Sorry, but what's your problem? `isValid` always returns `true`? Or `save` seems not working?

Comment: @user1248256, the problem appears to be `handleError` is triggered, but in `saveTodo`, `@model.isValid` returns true, I am thinking, this maybe due to model detected as invalid and thus not saved. So when it goes to `isValid`, its valid since model is not changed?

Comment: maybe `handleError` is triggered by `save` method? hm, where do you call `save` method?

Comment: In this version, I missed out the save method. But I think even with that missing, this should still work? I'd expect `isValid` to return false?

Comment: > "Try adding a todo, then try to make the todo blank. Notice it closes the edit mode". 
It seems it works correctly to me. When I try to add a blank todo, I see "Please specify a todo", the edit mode doesn't close and a todo isn't added.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand the question however as I read it you have a model in which you try to save some information you've just entered.

The models validate method will automatically return an error on setting the values of the model.

For instance:

```
var TodoModel = Backbone.Model.extend({ 

    defaults: {
       title: '',
       closed: 'false'
    },

    validate: function(attr) {

        if (attr.title === '') {
            console.log("Title expected");
        }

    }
});
```

Now when you create a new instance of this object (so you did not save any information in the model yet) the model isValid will return false:

```
var todo = new TodoModel();
console.log(todo.isValid()); //will be false
```

I don't know where you got the save function from. If you would like to place data into the todo model you can do it like this:

```
var todo = new TodoModel();
todo.set({
    'title': 'Figure out Backbone JS'
});

console.log(todo.isValid()); //must now return true
```

Of course you can also set these values imediatly:

```
var todo = new TodoModel({
    'title': 'still figuring out'
});

console.log(todo.isValid()); //still returns true
```

So this is the way to do validation checking.

Answer (score 0):

Calling the `save()` method on Backbone.Model with data in the same way as a `set()` call makes it a combined set/save call. Validation through your custom `validate()` method is done automatically on `save()`, but not when using `set()`.

I've never actually used the `isValid()` method because the Backbone documentation recommends instead listening for the `invalid` event and responding to validation errors there. All `isValid()` does is run the validation method that you have defined (if any), and return a boolean value, triggering the `invalid` event if your `validate()` method return anything other than `null`.

Note that versions of Backbone.Model prior to 1.0.0 incorrectly triggered an `error` event instead of an `invalid` event when validation failed.